# Delete characters from cursor up to the beginning

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I'm confused, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> deletes characters from the cursor up to the end of the line. But why does <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> delete the whole line?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> delete characters from the current cursor position until the beginning of the line. If the current cursor position is at the end of the line, of course that all the line will be deleted.

See also: [How do I clear/delete the current line in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9679776/2353900)